# If I use FCM device group feature, how would I know if any one of the tokens registered in the device group is no longer valid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

For instance, if user uses both phone and tablet to install an app, I will be able to create a device group with these two devices' tokens registered.

However, if the user deletes the app in the tablet without logging out from the app (thus skipping the step of FCM registration token removal workflow during logout), the tablet's FCM token will still remain in the device group in Firebase.

If I continue to use `notification key` to submit FCM notifications, I wouldn't be able to know that one of the registration token in the device group is invalid.

**Is there a way to figure out if any one of the registration token registered in the device group is invalid?**

I am asking this question as I am not seeing much benefits of using device group feature in FCM, when I could theoretically manage a list of FCM tokens for each user on my own in a database with full control.